# Getting TypeError: Object has no method 'find'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

Getting `TypeError: Object  has no method 'find'` whenever i use `find()` to check inside the returned object.

I don't have any idea how to get else in the object, I get the same error whenever using `findOne(), forEach() etc. etc.`

```
getChannels.findOne(query, function(err, data){
                if(data){
                    data.banlist.find(function(list){
                        var currentTime = Date.now();
                        var banTime = list ? list.bantime : "";
                        if(currentTime >= banTime){
                            var index = data.banlist.indexOf(list);
                            data.banlist.splice(index, 1)
                            data.save();
                        }
                    })  
                }       
            })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Documents can be retrieved through several static helper methods of
>   **models**.

in the above quote document means the database record.

when you do `.findOne(query, function(err, data)` you get returned documents or a document. findOne in this case is one document(one record). You see, your getting back a document not a Model. to use a query method **you need to use it on a Model**.

I'm assuming `getChannels` is a Model so when your return a document. you could get something else from `getChannels` in the callback.

some thing like this. not working code.

```
getChannels.findOne(query, function(err, data){
                if(data){
                    //query anyother Model or collection
                    getChannels.find(function(list){
                        var currentTime = Date.now();
                        var banTime = list ? list.bantime : "";
                        if(currentTime >= banTime){
                            var index = data.banlist.indexOf(list);
                            data.banlist.splice(index, 1)
                            data.save();
                        }
                    })  
                }       
            })
})
```